# How do you figure out where com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx happens?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression

We are using beans and expression language on our XPage and we get the above error from time to time, can anyone tell us if there is an easy way to find out which page is causing this and more importantly where in code? We are having to use trial and error methods and having to resort to remove code from page in order to find out where the problem is, which is not the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Does looking at the XPages log files not help? They show more details such as what xpage and details on the error. The XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF makes it easy to look in the log files

Comment: Many thanks Per, I had forgotten about that Gem, I am going to give it a try now to see if that could help.

Comment: Many thanks Per, that did the trick and it shows all the information we need to see for these type of errors, please post it as an answer so I can accept this solution - I had tons of Java errors yesterday getting this to work, which went away today for some reason (maybe because I copied the Jar files in my local jvm\lib\ext folder) therefore the delayed response!!

Comment: Great to hear. I've added an answer, Samir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the XPages log files in the IBM_Technical_Support folder in the data directory in order to get more details on the error such as what xpage gave the error and specific details on the error.

If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use [XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Like Fredrik Norling I will also recommend the [XPages OpenLog Logger by Paul Withers](http://openntf.org/p/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger) as a solution to generating error log files automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I would implement Paul Withers XPages Openlog implementation with the phase listening bean and error page.
That will help you find the problem. And if you deploy it as an osgi then you only have to set the error page, some xsp properties and add the bean to the faces config file on each database to point it to a central openlog error database.

http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger

http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=OpenLog

Comment: Many thanks Fredrik for your prompt response, we already have Paul's Openlog implementation with the phase listener, but OpenLog does not pick up these errors. We were eventually able to trace the error with trial and error, it was a case issue with one of the java bean method calls. But we are none the wiser about a solution for these type of errors.