# XPage Stack Source database IBM Domino

Tags: http, jvm, xpages, lotus-domino

I have some Domino servers where we run Xpage based applications. I have some issue with some HTTP JVM errors that I can find in the log from time to time can I in anyway get some more debug on the Domino server so that I can see what database this errors is occurring in?:

```
21-09-2015 11:26:58   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unable to get document page name for 39BCBE02FB280012C1257CE7006DEF2D
21-09-2015 11:26:58   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you figure out where com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620076/how-do-you-figure-out-where-com-ibm-xsp-exception-evaluationexceptionex-happens)

Answer (score 2):

The code is failing on trying to open the XPage associated with the specific document. It's looking to the form and can't find the relevant XPage.

Follow the answer on the question Per links to. Without viewing the logs, there's no way for anyone who does not have access to your server to tell you which database, which Form or which XPage.